# How to show single spinner in all activities in application?

Tags: android

I am creating spinner dialog to power off and restart which I show on keydown. The problem is I don't want to create spinner on each activity. So how can I call single spinner on all activities in application???

```
           public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Spinner spinner;

 String[] strings = {"Power Options","Power off","Restart"};

  String[] subs = {"","Shut phone down","Close all apps and restart phone" };

    int arr_images[] = {R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.images1,
          R.drawable.images2};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
      spinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row, strings));




        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
        { 

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, 
           View view, int i, long l) { 
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (i == 1)
                {

                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"PowerOff 
                       Perform",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                }


                if (i == 2)
                {



      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Reboot Perform",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }




             }
              // If no option selected
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  } 

      });




     }



public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

      public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,   String[] objects) 
     {
          super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
      }

      @Override
      public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {







          return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {




          return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
      }


      public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



          LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
          View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
          TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.company);
          label.setText(strings[position]);

          TextView sub=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.sub);
          sub.setText(subs[position]);

          ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image);
          icon.setImageResource(arr_images[position]); 

          return row;
          }








@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PAGE_UP == event.getKeyCode() && isRooted()){

      spinner.performClick();





           return true;

  }
 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class called BaseActivity and extend it to Activity. Then you can create your activities from BaseActivity class and add a dialog to it.

Edit:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

and your MainActivity will extend BaseActivity.

Comment: how give example? im showing spiiner in onkeydown method
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

Comment: Add the spinner and the dialog to your BaseActivity. This will make all your activities have the dialog since they extend to BaseActivity.

Comment: it is possiblr crete activity which extend spinner? so when i need spiner i call that activity using intent???

Comment: how i call baseActivity spiner on my main acivity?

Comment: this ketdown call on application level? i press anywhere in activity power button spinner will show me???

Comment: you don't have to. Since your main activity extends to BaseActivity class, when you trigger onKeyDown listener, BaseActivity classes onKeyDown will triggered.

Comment: Well if all of your activities are extended to BaseActivity class, then yes. Since they all extend to the same one activity class called BaseActivity, they will all act same and trigger the same onKeyDown method.

Comment: Well what i meant was, wherever you use "extend Activity" you use "extend BaseActivity" or if you have, lets say ListActivity, you create another class with the spinner and dialog called BaseListActivity.